# Why does calling more than one custom method from drawRect() crash Xcode playground after continuously redrawing?

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I realized a weird behavior that prevents me from using Xcode Playground for developing my custom view. Let's start with a minimal reproducible example:

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground

class WierdView : NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        drawNothing()
        // Uncomment the second call to drawNothing() and drawRect will get called 
        // repeatedly until the playground chrashes.
//        drawNothing()
        println("drewn.")
    }

    func drawNothing() {}
}

let wierd = WierdView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
XCPShowView("WierdView", wierd)
```

If you uncomment the second call to drawNothing() Xcode Playground will call drawRect() a few thousand times (which Playground will nicely indicate on the sidebar) until it crashes with following message:

**Error running playground.**
*An error occurred while trying to communicate with a helper application. You may need to restart Xcode before playgrounds will run again.*

You need to restart Xcode to use the Playground again. It seems to me that this is a bug in Xcode, but I was not able to find a corresponding bug report. So maybe I am doing something wrong? Is this reproducible to others?

Comment: Looks like a bug, please file a bug report.